# JSON Array rearrange/or filter by value of subvalue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm a bit stuck with a problem getting information out of a JSON array.
I know how to retrieve information and to parse them. So this isn't the issue. To get the information from Facebook we use JQuery, which did it's job fine so fare.

Basically, what I need is to restructure the JSON output of the following link: https://graph.facebook.com/284521968232566/photos

Under tags, you'll see several items. I need actually to rearrange the whole thing to get all sorted by tag. That means:

```
Pauke    { [name, source, link], [name, source, link] }
Trompete { [name, source, link], [name, source, link] }
```

Obviously, as you can see, the top-level item has just one item, but as soon there are more pictures it'll grow.

This might be not the right form of the array, I'm open to your approaches.

Thank you

Comment: do you need only the rearranged tags object or the whole json modified?

Comment: I need it structured by tags. To give you some background: The JSON data is an output from an photo album on facebook of a band. In every picture you'll see a band member, tagged according the instruments they play. Therefore it can occur that someone plays more than one, which results in more than one tag. As a result the band member therefore needs to show up in more than one section on the webpage after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so just iterate over `data`, and then over `data[i].tags.data`, building a result array, somthing like:

```
var json = {} ; // The json data - this needs to be pre-populated
var result = [] ; // Result Array
var tag ; // Temporary variable for each tag in turn.

for(var i=0;i<json.data.length;i++) {
    if(    typeof json.data[i].tags != 'undefined'
        && typeof json.data[i].tags.data != 'undefined'
    ) {
        for(var j=0;j<json.data[i].tags.data.length;j++) {
            tag = json.data[i].tags.data[j] ;
            if(typeof(tag.name != 'undefined') {
                if(typeof result[tag.name] == 'undefined') result[tag.name] = [] ;
                result[tag.name][result[tag.name].length] = {
                    'name'    : tag.name,
                    'source'  : json.data[i].source,
                    'link'    : json.data[i].link
                } ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces an array (of tags), each of which is an array (of images), with one object containing the information for each image with that tag name.